# Simplifying expression to evaluate limit as $y\rightarrow 0$

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I often end up with a function that contains the term $1/(1 + x^2/y^2)$, and I need to evaluate this in the limit $y\rightarrow 0$. By hand, I can rewrite this as $y^2/(y^2 + x^2)$, but how can I tell *Mathematica* to make such a simplification?

I have tried using `1/(1 + x^2/y^2) // Simplify` and `Expand`, but neither work as intend (actually, they doesn't change anything).

Comment: You do not have to rewrite this expression, *MMA* can handle that form.

Comment: @Kuba When I use `1/(1 + x^2/y^2) /. y -> 0` I get an error, infinite expression

Comment: How about `Limit[1/(1 + x^2/y^2), y -> 0]`? (you replace `y`, and thus divide by 0)

Comment: @PinguinDirk shouldn't it return some conditional result? Check `Limit[1/(1 + x^2/y^2), y -> 0, Assumptions -> (x = 0)]`

Comment: @Kuba: good point! (maybe you want assumption `x==0` (syntax)). Actually, I have no idea why Mathematica (and so did I) automatically assumes $x\neq0$. Maybe somebody else?

Comment: @bills It is correct if `x!=0`...

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21544/finding-limits-in-several-variables

Comment: Perhaps also of interest for additional discussion of `Limit`: [How to evaluate the 0/0 type limit in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3797/245)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   expr = 1/(1 + x^2/y^2)

(*   1/(1 + x^2/y^2)  *)

Simplify[expr, ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, _Power[_, -2]] &)]

(* y^2/(x^2 + y^2) *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Like many limits involving two variables, this one is not as straightforward as it might seem. Consider

```
Limit[1/(1 + x^2/y^2), x -> 0]

1
```

while

```
Limit[1/(1 + x^2/y^2), y -> 0]

0
```

Coupling the two:

```
Limit[1/(1 + x^2/y^2) /. y -> x, x -> 0]

1/2
```

In other words, which direction you approach in x,y space is important to the limit. You can make this take almost any value between zero and one by choosing how the x,y are coupled. For example:

```
Limit[1/(1 + x^2/y^2) /. y -> 10 x, x -> 0]
Limit[1/(1 + x^2/y^2) /. y -> x/10, x -> 0]
```

give limits of 100/101 and 1/101. The same answers occur if the original form is replaced by the OPs simpler form, y^2/(x^2 + y^2).

There is a discussion of the use of [generic solutions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericSolutions.html), which appears to be the reason that the first two give different answers: effectively the second is assuming that "generically" x is not zero. The tutorial doesn't explicitly mention `Limit` though presumably `Solve` is being used rather than `Reduce` (or at least, the methodology of `Solve` is being used rather than the methodology of `Reduce`) in terms of generic solutions.

Comment: @Penguin Dirk - I thought you should have elaborated!

Comment: @PinguinDirk Agree, almost because the thing is the first line shouldn't give us `1` without any assumptions. Also with, not bold at all, assumption that `x` and `y` are independent this `limit[x,y]` is the same as `KronockerDelta[x]`, in values terms ofc.